# Caption doesn not align with graphic in marginpar mode

Tags: graphics, captions, marginpar

Want to include a graphic in the margin. Without `\centering` the graphic is to the left and the caption is shifted to the right and not even fully visible. When `\centering` is included the graphic is shifted far right where the caption is glued. How do I work around this?

```
\leavevmode\marginpar{
\begin{figure}[H]
%\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{ThiSulfat2D.png}
\caption{Thiosulfat, \ch{(S2O^{2-}3)}}
\label{fig4}
\end{figure}
}
```

My preamble

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,fleqn,reqno]{article}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
textwidth = 280pt,
marginparwidth=178pt,
marginparsep = 40pt,
lmargin = 90pt
}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.9cm}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black,
    pdfborder = {0 0 0}
}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{steinmetz}
\newcommand*\mycirc[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(0,-0.1)}]
\node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt] {#1};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{
  font=small,
  labelfont=bf,
  tableposition=top
}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{chemformula}
%\usepackage{chemmacros}
%\chemsetup{modules=all}
\usepackage{elements}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{layout}
```

Comment: As always on the site. please provide a full but minimal example others can copy and test as is. Here we have no idea what class and preamble you're using.

Comment: @daleif Added the preamble. Sorry.

Comment: Your image is probably too wide and is leaking out of the right margin.  You should be getting a wanring about overfull \hbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what is your problem. Maybe the following MWE gives what looking for:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,fleqn,reqno]{article}
\usepackage[textwidth = 280pt,
            marginparwidth=178pt,
            marginparsep = 40pt,
            lmargin = 90pt
            ]{geometry} 
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=small,
            labelfont=bf,
            tableposition=top
            ]{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\leavevmode\marginpar{
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\captionof{figure}{Thiosulfat, \ch{(S2O^{2-}3)}}
\label{fig4}
}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

(red lines indicate page layout)

[image]

Comment: Works beautifully! :-) Thanks!